# swift - How to set selection color when Multiple Selection is set to true in UITableVIew

Tags: ios, swift

If you set Multiple Selection to true, the color will change to the color you specify for each cell you touch.

But what I want is to set Multiple Selection to true and change only the color of the touching cell and the rest to white.

Is it possible to do this?

This is the source I am applying.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var btnCheck: UIButton!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        btnCheck.isSelected = true
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    } else {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        btnCheck.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of tableView's methods `func selectRow(at: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)` and it's `deselectRow` counterpart? I wonder if you wanted to be able to deselect a table cell? Then you could just check an `indexPathForSelectedRow` and deselect it if necessary. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Well, why not adding one boolean to cell as property? After that in didSelect just do negation of that boolean cell.isChecked = !cell.isChecked. On property observer set background color of cell by isChecked state...

Comment: @Stefan, there is already a boolean for that. It's called `isSelected`, why would you make another one? Just use one that already exists.

Comment: @igrek Why would you override system property, if you can create new one and make it customizable by your needs? I guess you know that abusing of system properties is not good idea, right?

Comment: @Stefan, because I find the system one to exactly meet the needs to customize selected state. Why making another property for the same sake

Comment: And what if you want to change color of specific cell programmaticaly e.g.? You'll force setSelected right?

Comment: @Stefan, it depends on what i need. If it's a selection then yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176314/discussion-between-igrek-and-stefan).

Comment: Okay, I have another approach of solving custom things, nothing bad with your's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with following code :
It works for me

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard  let cell : KichenListTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? KichenListTableViewCell else {
            return
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard  let cell  : KichenListTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? KichenListTableViewCell else {
        return
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Hope it will helps you.Thank you